# Add space/break line between two <a> tags using bootstrap only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am using PHP for loop to print 10 tags in a HTML page.

However, I need the `<a>` tags to appear in different lines with some space. I know this can be achieved using custom CSS, but is there any way to achieve it via bootstrap only?

I have added the HTML code for reference:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
  <span><?php echo $i + 1; ?>. </span><a class href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Expected output:

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui
10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et debitis magnam sint laboriosam mollitia qui

Comment: Add expected output so we can figure out what you exactly want to accomplish.

Comment: This is probably what you want: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Looking for an ordered list?

Comment: Also is this a PHP question at all? Can't you just post the rendered HTML and remove the PHP parts

Comment: Why not wrap in divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in divs?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div><span>1. </span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></div>
<div><span>2. </span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d-block` class to make `<a>` tag block elem so that each one starts from next line

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
    <div><span><?php echo $i + 1; ?>. </span>
    <a  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></div>
    <br />
<?php endfor; ?>
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#examples)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span>1. </span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
<span>2. </span><a  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
<span>3. </span><a  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
<span>4. </span><a  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
<span>5. </span><a  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need the <span> tag to be also in the same line. Using this solution that can't be achieved. The numbers and the <a> tags are in different line

Comment: @Deeptiranjan For that you need to wrap `a` and `span` inside some div, i updated my ans please have a look

Comment: No need to make the div a d-block. Also update the snippet I made you or see my answer

Comment: @mplungjan Agree i just comment above you need to add wrapper div. Thank for correction :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ordered list:

```
<ol>
<?php for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ): ?>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
</ol>
```